# How to open a URL using parse push notification?

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, push-notification, android-notifications

I implemented parse push notification in my app.But I only can send text notifications and when the user clicked on the notification it goes to app.
Now I want to open a url when the user clicked on the notification.What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You may parse url from push and "throw" intent:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(/**Your parsed url**/));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```